# Responsiveness of GUI of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS running on Virtual Box 5.2.12 is very choppy and sluggish

Tags: unity, graphics, virtualbox, 18.04, compiz

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on Vbox 5.2.12. To give you some context, calling it choppy would be an understatement, It is painfully slow. I have tried all the answers that I could find in the multiverse but I am still out of luck.

Ok, So everything is super snappy when I run commands on my terminal, but when I switch to GUI, it goes berserk, either it is too slow to respond or stutters a million times in a sec and gives me headaches.

> **Host Details:**
>
> ---
>
> **OS:** Windows 10 
>   **Physical Memory:** 16 GB 
>   **Graphics Memory:** 8GB (Intel UHD Graphics 620) 
>   **SSD:** 256 GB 
>   **Processor:** Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8650U CPU @ 1.90GHz, 2112 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s) 
>   **Virtualization:** Enabled
>
> **Guest Details:**
>
> ---
>
> **OS:** Ubuntu 18.04 
>   **RAM Allocated:** 8192 MB (Reason: Hope. Still no luck) 
>   **VRAM Allocated:** 256 MB (same reason as above) 
>   **Processor Count:** 4 
>   **Execution Cap:** 100% 
>   **3D Acceleration:** Enabled 
>   **Guest Additions:** Installed 
>   **Compiz Settings:** Disabled Animation,Fading 
>   **Is 3D Acceleration Supported:** Yes

```
raghu@devbox:~$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   Humper
OpenGL renderer string: Chromium
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Chromium 1.9

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

***Note:*** If you feel the answer that gets accepted is along the lines of the answers to previously asked questions, go ahead and mark it as a duplicate. Please wait at least until then. I have tried almost all the answers to similar questions and unfortunately, none of them worked for me.

Comment: What format are these "animations"? Did you try with 2, or 3  cores leaving at least 1 for the host? Same for memory: did you try with 2-4 GB for the guest? As I can see from above you had allocated **all** your memory to the guest (you should leave some for the host, especially if that was Windows).

Comment: By animation, I meant the default system animations like resizing of the window, closing, and opening of the window, dragging the window etc. Or more clearly, I mean GUI is not that responsive.It is choppy.

Comment: How do you install the guest OS? I've noticed that when I'm using the the automatic installation process the things get worse... So please create a new virtual machine and do not install anything during its creation. Then run the VM, mount an installation media and install Ubuntu as it is on a physical computer.

Comment: Have you installed Guest Additions into the guest? Set the guest VM at 2 CPU's, 2048 RAM, network as bridged. See if that helps.

Comment: It's gnome shell issue. You can't run shell om vm.

Answer (score 2):

Other than on bare metal a virtual machine does not always benefit from maxed out resources. This is because the supervisor (here Virtual Box) running on the host will also need some resources to run smoothly.

1. **Memory**

   Leave as much memory for the host OS to operate without having to swap on the hard drive. If we had used 8 GB of 16 GB for an intergrated GPU then from the remaining 8 GB leave 2 GB or more for the host.
2. **CPU**

   It is true that any guest OS will run the better the more cores we assign to the guest. If we assign all cores we may slow down the host and the performance of the virtual machine slows down with it. So it is often better to leave at least one core to the host, or define an execution cap of say 90% in the VirtualBox settings.
3. **Hard drive**

   By using a dynamically growing drive we can assign a huge virtual drive that is physically much smaller as long as it was not filled with data. It will only use as much space as needed.
4. **Graphics card**

   For 3D acceleration the host GPU is passed through to the guest with the guest additions graphics driver. This also means that all graphic card memory can also by accessed from the guest. Increasing the guest VGA memory to more than 128 MB is rarely needed.

Comment: Agreed, but I did try running the VM with those settings but the result was still the same, that's why I bumped up everything.

Comment: Okay, Just to reassure myself, I tried to lower it and run. Still no luck.

Comment: @RaghuVeerS: just because the behaviour you report is so unusal and for reassurance - you did reboot the guest in between changing settings, and it is not an architecture issue (32/64 bit)?

Comment: Yes, I did reboot the guest. If you mean by OS architecture, both the guest and host have 64 bit kernel.

Comment: Also, the Virtual Box edition that I downloaded is a 64-bit one.

Comment: Is your guest attached to the host network? Sometimes Ubuntu can spend quite some time searching for it.

Comment: Yes via NAT, but how could that slow down only the gui performance?

Comment: Do you think the problem could be because of gnome?

Comment: @RaghuVeerS: no idea, really - with my VM a 18.04 guest performs ok (host 16.04 AMD A8 @3500) - not a speed beast but ok.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

I installed the last virtuabox version on windows 10 pro.
I create a new vm and install the last ubuntu desktop (18.04.version on it.
When i open it, everything is so slow.

I download the "ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso" and install it. This one work fine. even before installing the guest tools...

This is strange....

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, in my case my host is MAC OS High Sierra 10.13.6

I tried Ubuntu 18.04 and tried small to max settings with all similar results for the Gnome Desktop.
With hardware acceleration ON and the Guest Additions properly configured, it would run ok for a short while (several seconds to a few minutes) but the moment I started moving windows around in the desktop or doing anything that taxes Gnome Desktop, gnome-shell starts going 100% constantly.

I tried the latest CentOS 7 and exact same behaviour with the exact same process.

I did what @user1571627 said and **downloaded Ubuntu 16.04.5 and voila!  Everything just works fantastically with Unity!**

So the only conclusion that I can make is that the gnome-shell process for the new Gnome Desktop isn't properly accelerated by the Guest Additions extension of Virtualbox.

Perhaps in time they'll sort it out.  For now we've got a mature Unity (which I believe is WAY better than Gnome Desktop when it comes to usability and performance anyway) in a supported LTS version of Ubuntu.  So you can use that as your guest.